# How to build MEAN stack development environment with GitHub?

Tags: node.js, git, jenkins, mean-stack

I am newbie to MEAN stack building MEAN stack development environment for start-up project(web service). Below is a topology where I build up MEAN stack environment.

```
topology image link: http://147.46.215.116/Picture1.png
```

Remote PC which developers will use Sublime Text(Code Editor) to code. Git client, NodeJS, its plugins and other stuffs(bower, grunt-client and so on...) are also set on their PC.
 I made a Git-hub repository (forked from https://github.com/linnovate/mean.git) for SCM. I also built Jenkins server for CI. Web server is on cloud(Digital ocean).

When I started sample MEAN web service on each machine, It worked like a charm.
After typing following commands, I could see the empty sample page at localhost:3000.

```
 git clone https://github.com/myname/mean.git (which is forked from ~/linnovate/mean.git)
 cd mean && npm install
 grunt
```

Here is where my trouble started.

At remote PC, I modified a js source a little bit, and I pushed this to the git-hub repository. It seemed that, by setting .gitignore, MEAN stack didn't let whole project files pushed to git-hub. Instead, it uploaded small part of the project, requiring developers 'npm install' when they git-cloned the project.

One newbie developer git-cloned this project to his remote PC. After 'npm install'ed, however, it didn't work. This is what came up instead.

```
[4mRunning "clean:0" (clean) task[24m
[4mRunning "jshint:all" (jshint) task[24m

[1m   Gruntfile.js[22m
      1 |[90m'use strict';[39m
         ^ Use the function form of "use strict".
      9 |[90mmodule.exports = function(grunt) {[39m
         ^ 'module' is not defined.
     11 |[90m    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {[39m
                 ^ 'process' is not defined.
     12 |[90m        require('time-grunt')(grunt);[39m
                 ^ 'require' is not defined.
......
```

Here's my question.

1. Is it right to 'npm install' whenever I git-cloned/pulled the project?
   How do you guys usually develop web service project w/ MEAN stack and Git?
   I wonder whether I misunderstood mean stack development(w/ git) process.
2. If it is, why doesn't it work?
3. I also feel confused while using Jenkins. If 'npm install' should happen whenever builds,
   Should 'npm install' process occur in Jenkins server (and output files goes to web server)?
   or in web server (after just source files are transferred to web server)?

a grass-hopper waits for you guys advice. please help-.

Comment: I think it would be helpful for you to edit your question. It looks like you are asking at least two questions here. I suggest pulling the Jenkins part into a separate question. Did you figure out an answer to your questions yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTFM

How to install MEAN.js http://meanjs.org/docs.html#getting-started

How to deploy via Git http://krisjordan.com/essays/setting-up-push-to-deploy-with-git

If you do now understand how to use Git and MEAN.js what the reason to make things worth and to use Jenkins?